# Tiling seamless diagonal lines

Tags: patterns, effects

I'm working on a tile-based game, and I'd like to have diagonal lines for (32x32) tiles. The problem is, whenever you tile them, they look like this:

[image]

How do I make it seamlessly tile?

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-do-a-tile-with-diagonal-lines-in-photoshop

Comment: Seemingly so, but I have a different question and that, unfortunately, had no usable solution.

Comment: "How" depends entirely on what tool(s) you're using. Since you don't say, the question as written doesn't contain enough information for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 5):

If your lines should perfectly align to pixels, then you must choose a spacing that's a divisor of 32.

This leaves you with line-spacings of 2, 4, 8 and 16. And since 1 pixel is occupied by the line itself, your possible "blank" lines between your lines are 1, 3, 7 and 15.

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe Generator](http://www.stripegenerator.com) should do the trick for you.

Comment: This was the answer that I provided on this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-do-a-tile-with-diagonal-lines-in-photoshop which mpnk121 stated is not what he's looking for.